# BizTalk 2010 Monitoring File Location

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a situation where my biztalk app processes PDF's by their name and sorts them to their corresponding file locations. My question is Is there a way to monitor one folder and only send out a maximum of one email per 24 hours if a file is in that folder location? I have a folder that is a catch all and I don't want an email sent for every message. Just one reminder email every 24 hours IF there is a file( or more ) in that location. Thanks all.

Comment: Perhaps the [BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter](http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/) would help you with the periodic email functionality?

Comment: Thanks Tom. I Figured i may have to create a custom adapter. Ill Look into this instead.

Comment: Using BizTalk and a custom adapter seems a little over-kill if you're not actually processing the files at this point. I would just write a little Powershell script and run that using Task Scheduler.

Comment: Or you could put a schedule on the receive location so that it only activates for one minute at the same time each day and have a singleton Orchestration to get all of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a variant of the Sequential Convoy.

Start here: http://biztalkvillage.blogspot.com/2012/12/sequential-convoy-using-listen-shape-in.html

Your Reminder Orchestration would subscribe to messages with data you want to e-mail to the users, either the original PDF emessages them selves or a custom message generated by the existing process.

In your case, the Listen Shape's Delay Shape would be initialized to the time of day you want to sent the e-mail.  4pm, 5pm, whenever.

As additional messages are received, you can build a list or just ignore them.  At the end of the Orch, format and send the Message (by smtp).

Either way, the "Files Received" message will only be sent if >0 PDF's arrive.

Comment: If the orchestration terminates (manually or by exception) the email won't be sent unless another message arrives before the next alert time. Depending on volumes this could be very unlikely so it might be an acceptable risk.

Comment: Well sure, but really not more/less risk than any other solution.  Actually, the only risk scenario would be if an Admin terminated the Reminder after the last message of the period.  It would reactivate if a subsequent message arrives.